# HTML : Parse, Analyze, and Reconstruct in mobile site

Tags: html, web-applications, mobile, computer-science

I am working on a school project for me CS class where we are to find an application that is interesting to us and figure out how it works. 
I have picked the technology on [dudamobile.com](http://dudamobile.com)

The app takes a URL and then converts the desktop version of a website into a mobile version.

I think I have a basic understanding out how this works....

1. Clean up the HTML
2. Parse the HTML and look for key tags
3. Store key tags in variables
4. Apply variables to a premade mobile HTML template
5. insert custom CSS to fit mobile devices

This is a pretty high level analysis, my question is what specific tools can I use to create something similar for my project? Is my analysis correct, in your opinion?

Comment: The tools depend on the programming language ...

Comment: I am assuming a server side language like PHP with JavaScript integration would work

Comment: I'm not sure they really do step 2/3 as much as they just copy over those tags, from the looks of it.

Answer (score 0):

To me it just looks like they strip out large sections of css and replace it with more mobile friendly and less graphic intensive css. It also seems to choose odd links in navigation to make the top links so some kind of algorithm there (the top links of my site were all the ones I had for mobile devices).

I would start by doing a few tricks on the css files the site uses and strip out background images, changing images over a certain width into block level elements, changing font size, etc. until you get it looking like more of a simple layout and then add the other mobile elements  as you see fit (making it readable without zooming is probably the most important though).

If the site uses html5 you can apply different css rules to the navigation section to make it a list of links and move it to the top.

Don't expect it to be a perfect crossover unless the site is moderately simple though.

You would need a back end technology to retrieve and parse the .css file to re-serve it. I would suggest whatever language you're comfortable with. I don't have much experience in PHP but I believe it would be a good fit for that application.